# Div dropdown menu overlaying other content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when you click an icon in a div, there is a dropdown box that shows up and overlays the div's content.  But right now, my dropdown box is simply pushing down the div's content, rather than overlaying it.  After browsing similar questions on this site, I'm almost certain the problem is in my CSS having to make some elements position:relative and other elements position: absolute, but I've been playing with it for a while and can't seem to get it to work properly.  Below is a clean version of my code (without the various position attempts).

The relevant CSS code is:

```
#ideas_box {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 1110px;

    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;

    border: solid 1px #6a6a6a;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cecdcd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cecdcd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cecdcd;
}

#ideas_box_majority_bar_green{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;  /* for making green bar as large as parent div */
    padding-bottom: 1000px; /* for making green bar as large as parent div */
    background-color: #a8fba6;
}

#ideas_box_main_content {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
}

#ideas_box_top {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ideas_box_top_image {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
}

#ideas_box_top_titlebar {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#ideas_box_top_titlebar_title {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #060708;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 150%;
}

#ideas_box_top_titlebar_postInfo {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #363636;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 80%;
}

#ideas_box_top_iconBar {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#ideas_box_top_iconBar_comment {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #060708;
    font-family: "Arial";
}

#ideas_box_top_iconBar_thumbsUp {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #060708;
    font-family: "Arial";
}

#ideas_box_top_iconBar_thumbsDown {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #060708;
    font-family: "Arial";
}

#ideas_box_content {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-right: 40px;
}


#comments_dropDown_box_point {
    display: none;

    width: 20px;
    height: 14px;
    position: relative;

    left: 13px;
    top: 3px;

    background:url('../img/box_point.png'); 

    z-index: 10;
}

#comments_dropDown_box {
    display: none;

    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 1px #C2C2C2;
    overflow: auto;

    left: -13px;
    top: 2px;

    z-index: 9;

    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;

    border: solid 1px #C2C2C2;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cecdcd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cecdcd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cecdcd;
}

#comments_dropDown_box .comments_dropDown_row {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    font-style: italic;
}

#comments_dropDown_box .dropDown_divider {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #dfdede;
}
```

The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xml; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts_ideaboard.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ideaboard.css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- LIST -->
    <div id="ideas_box">
        <div id="ideas_box_majority_bar_green"></div>
        <div id="ideas_box_main_content">
            <div id="ideas_box_top">
                <div id="ideas_box_top_image"></div>
                <div id="ideas_box_top_titlebar">
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_titlebar_title">Test</div>
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_titlebar_postInfo">Test on Aug 09 2017, 08:37:58pm</div>
                </div>
                <div id="ideas_box_top_iconBar">
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_iconBar_comment">
                        <img src="img/comments.jpg" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"><br>
                        +8
                        <!-- display drop down for comments -->
                            <div id="comments_dropDown_box_point"></div>
                            <div id="comments_dropDown_box">
                                <div class="comments_dropDown_row">
                                    User1
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropDown_divider"></div>
                                <div class="comments_dropDown_row">
                                    User2
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropDown_divider"></div>
                                <div class="comments_dropDown_row">
                                    User3
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!-- END display drop down for comments -->
                    </div>
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_iconBar_thumbsUp">
                        <img src="img/like.jpg" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"><br>
                        +3
                    </div>
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_iconBar_thumbsDown">
                        <img src="img/dislike.jpg" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"><br>
                        -2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ideas_box_content">
            This is a test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- LIST -->
    <div id="ideas_box">
        <div id="ideas_box_majority_bar_green"></div>
        <div id="ideas_box_main_content">
            <div id="ideas_box_top">
                <div id="ideas_box_top_image"></div>
                <div id="ideas_box_top_titlebar">
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_titlebar_title">Test</div>
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_titlebar_postInfo">Test on Aug 09 2017, 08:37:58pm</div>
                </div>
                <div id="ideas_box_top_iconBar">
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_iconBar_comment">
                        <img src="img/comments.jpg" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"><br>
                        +8
                        <!-- display drop down for comments -->
                            <div id="comments_dropDown_box_point"></div>
                            <div id="comments_dropDown_box">
                                <div class="comments_dropDown_row">
                                    User1
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropDown_divider"></div>
                                <div class="comments_dropDown_row">
                                    User2
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropDown_divider"></div>
                                <div class="comments_dropDown_row">
                                    User3
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <!-- END display drop down for comments -->
                    </div>
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_iconBar_thumbsUp">
                        <img src="img/like.jpg" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"><br>
                        +3
                    </div>
                    <div id="ideas_box_top_iconBar_thumbsDown">
                        <img src="img/dislike.jpg" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;"><br>
                        -2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ideas_box_content">
            This is a test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

The JS code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#ideas_box_top_iconBar_comment").click(function()
    {
        $("#comments_dropDown_box").toggle();
        $("#comments_dropDown_box_point").toggle();
    });


});
```

A live version is here:  http://quickid.net/test/ideaboard.html  (click comment icon in first post)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You're absolutely right that the problem has something to do with the position: relative and position: absolute. 

But currently, it looks like you're utilizing overflow:hidden on some of your parent elements (#ideas_box and #ideas_box_top_iconBar). You're going to need to reformat your css a little bit in order to make it so you don't need the overflow: hidden. Otherwise, you won't be able to get your "tooltip" divs to "overflow" out of the div. They'll only be hidden.

Comment: Also - it's important to note that you're going to want only one "id" per page. Currently, it looks like you'll be repeating `ideas_box` often.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help, worked perfect!

Comment: of course! If my answer below was what helped, go ahead and mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment - you'll have to do a bit more reformatting with the rest of your code to get this working exactly as you want it, but I had some time so I thought I'd show you how to make the whole `position: relative` and `position: absolute`.

First off, I changed all ids to classes and removed your `overflow: hidden` on your parent elements - with this active, there would be no way to have your "tooltip" pop out of your div. That - of course - ruins how you have your green line working, but it allows us to get the tool tip working.

After that, I added `position: relative` to your `.ideas_box_top_iconBar_comment` since this will be the class that parents the tooltip arrow.

I then wrapped the tooltip arrow & menu in a `.comments_dropDown_boxWrapper` and has the following css:

```
.comments_dropDown_boxWrapper { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

Then after some changing of the javascript to work with the new wrapper class, we have it working!

Here's the jsfiddle so you can see it all in action. This isn't a step-by-step solution to what you're doing, but I'm hoping it gives you enough to help you solve it on your own.

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yt8Ltu31/

Answer (score 0):

Set it to `position: absolute` and then do `z-index: 1`